# Powershell - How do I extract the first line of all text files in a directory into a single output file?

Tags: powershell, text, large-files

I have a directory with about 10'000 text files of varying lengths. All over 1GB in size.

I need to extract the first line of each file and insert it into a new text file in the same directory.

I've tried the usual MS-DOS batch file method, and it crashes due to the files being too large.

Is there a way of doing this in Powershell using Streamreader?

Comment: A combination of `Get-Content` and `Out-File` cmdlets will achieve this, google them.

Comment: Thanks for your... "Helpful" advice. Actually Get-Content loads the entire contents of a file to memory before it does anything with it. I have actually tried using it for large files before and on a 1GB file it allocated 8GB of RAM, used it all up, then started paging to disk for about 8 hours before it counted one line. Not really ideal for a job that needs to repeat 10'000 times. "Google it" is not really the kind of advice I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to read only one line, you can also use :

```
$file = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($filename)
$file.ReadLine()
$file.close()
```

Using [OutVariable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx) you can write it in one line :

```
$text = (new-object System.IO.StreamReader($filename) -OutVariable $file).ReadLine();$file.Close()
```

Answer (score 13):

**EDIT**: Of course there in an inbuilt way:

```
$firstLine = Get-Content -Path $fileName -TotalCount 1
```

[Ack [Raf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3153152/raf)'s comment]

---

Original:

I would suggest looking at [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383357.aspx): this method reads the contents of the file lazily – only reading content with each iteration over the returned enumerator.

I'm not sure if `Select-Object -first 1` will pro-actively halt the pipeline after one line, if it does then that is the easiest way to get the first line:

```
$firstLine = [IO.File]::ReadLines($filename, [text.encoding]::UTF8) | Select-Object -first 1
```

Otherwise something like:

```
$lines = [IO.File]::ReadLines($filename, [text.encoding]::UTF8); # adjust to correct encoding
$lineEnum = $lines.GetEncumerator();
if ($lineEnum.MoveNext()) {
  $firstLine = $lineEnum.Current;
} else {
  # No lines in file
}
```

NB. this assumes at least PowerShell V3 to use .NET V4.

Comment: Thanks! As my files are over 1GB, and "Get-Content" loads the entire file into memory before attempting to "get" the "content" of it, I cannot use your top suggestion. However your third suggestion worked perfectly! :)

Comment: The top suggestion will work fine.  Test it against a 1GB file (using the -TotalCount parameter) and see if it doesn't immediately return the first line.

Answer (score 3):

Short and sweet:

```
cd c:\path\to\my\text\files\
Get-Content *.txt -First 1 > output.txt
```

Edit Nov 2018: According to the docs, "*The TotalCount parameter limits the retrieval to the first n lines.*" This appears to minimize resource usage.  Test it yourself and add your comments.

```
cd c:\path\to\my\text\files\
Get-Content *.txt -TotalCount 1 > output.txt
```

Comment: This loads the whole file into memory which won't work in this case / is not ideal.